# Select This Year and Previous Year mysql on Same Row

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I'm struggling to select the COUNT of 2 fields grouped with this_year_total and last_year as the total for date - 1 year. I've tried with no solution working so far

This is once method tried, but may highlight better what I'm trying to achieve.

```
SELECT `date`, `model`,
SUM(YEAR(`date`)  = YEAR(CURDATE())) as this_year,
SUM(YEAR(`date`)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1) as last_year

FROM `sales`

WHERE YEAR(`date`) IN (YEAR(CURDATE()), YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1)

GROUP BY date, model DESC;
```

The desired output is

date | model | this year (Count of id) | last_year (Count of id)

All input appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want:

```
select
    model,
    max(date) date
    sum(date >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-01-01')) this_year,
    sum(date < date_format(current_date, '%Y-01-01')) last_year
from sales
where date >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-01-01')) - interval 1 year
group by model, date_format(date, '%m-%d')
```

Comment: Hi many thanks, I think my issue is needing to group on date and model, this would sum the whole year not split by date, I need date ('2020-05-13') that selects the count of model for the current field date as this_year and where date = ('2019-05-13' ) | model | count of model as last_year.  Each model is multiple records that count as 1 for each day.  Appreciate your help

Comment: @SimonCrowther: I think I see what you mean. See my updated answer.